# How to register a micrometer counter in Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, prometheus, micrometer, spring-micrometer

I am trying to add simple micrometer `Counter` and have it exported through `/actuator/prometheus`.
My first attempt was simply do inject a `MeterRegistry` and `register` the `Counter` in the service constructor

```java
@Service
public class MyService {

    private final Counter fooCounter;

    public MyClass(MeterRegistry meterRegistry) {
        fooCounter = Counter.builder("foo.count")
            .baseUnit("nr of foos")
            .register(meterRegistry);
    }

    public void foo() {
        fooCounter.increment();
    }
```

By doing the above the metric became available under `/actuator/metrics/foo.count` as expected, however it was not available under `/actuator/prometheus` even though other metrics are. This was the ChatGPT suggestion.
Next, I tried to implement `MeterBinder` in `MyService`:

```java
@Service
public class MyService {

    private Counter fooCounter;

    public MyClass() {}

    public void foo() {
        fooCounter.increment();
    }

    @Override
    public void bindTo(MeterRegistry meterRegistry) {
        fooCounter = Counter.builder("foo.count")
            .baseUnit("nr of foos")
            .register(meterRegistry);
    }
```

Now, it did become available under `/actuator/prometheus`, however it seems there are now 2 instances of the `Counter`, only one of which is actually incremented in the `foo`-method, so this does not seem correct either. `/actuator/metrics/foo.count` does answer with the expected data, except that the value is never incremented.
For completeness, I am using Spring 2.7.15 and micrometer 1.9.14 and here is my `MeterRegistry`-bean

```java
@Configuration
public class MetricsConfig {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public MeterRegistry metricRegistry() {
        return new PrometheusMeterRegistry(PrometheusConfig.DEFAULT);
    }
}
```

How do I correctly register a `Counter` so that it is included in all the `MeterRegistries`?

Comment: Why do you need the custom registry? You are not configuring anything in it and Boot creates one for you. I think the problem is that you somehow two registries are created and Boot is only aware one of them.

Instead of asking ChatGPT, try to generate a project using start.spring.io

Comment: The code base is inherited, it was configured this way. I'll test to run without the registry config.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you haven't exposed prometheus via your application properties:

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include: health,info,prometheus
```

In this [GitHub repository](https://github.com/Lefeverw/stackoverflow-spring-micrometer) I created an example app that has a metric `numberOfGets` which is incremented after executing a GET request. The metric is available on the endpoint `/actuator/prometheus`. You could use this example to verify what's wrong in your case.

Give a shout if I can help with other aspects.

Comment: The `/actuator/prometheus` endpoint is exposed as it returns other metrics. I'll clarify in the question